# How to efficiently find elements in list A that aren't in list B?

Tags: list-manipulation

Every element in List A appears only once, and the same is true for List B.
How can I efficiently create a list of the element in A that don't appear in B?
Obviously, I can just do this:

```
Do[A=DeleteDuplicates[A,B[[i]]],{i,1,Length[B]}];
```

...but that's painfully slow for very long lists.  Also, it doesn't take advantage of my knowledge that every element in each list is unique within the list.

Thanks!

Comment: `Complement[B, A]` ?

Comment: @cvgmt  Seriously, that simple?  Well, if you want to post that as an Answer, I'll Accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
A = RandomInteger[10, 10]
B = RandomInteger[10, 8]
Complement[A, B]
```